# Positioning div elements

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the text that I have in the paragraph tags under the slideshow and not behind/in it. How would I go about that?

```css
.astro {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  91.66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="astro">
  <img src="https://images.complex.com/complex/images/c_crop,h_1009,w_1793,x_35,y_191/c_fill,g_center,w_1200/fl_lossy,pg_1,q_auto/bml3jrfcmmnhveupv5wq/astroworld-lead-sarah-montgomery" />
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DsRG3ldU0AAmswD.jpg:large" />
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtEDa3EUcAA_QJ6.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="tour-bio">
  <h3>ASTROWORLD:Wish you Were Here Tour </h3>
  <p>Praesent luctus dapibus felis sit amet egestas. Donec dignissim sapien eget erat euismod, ac euismod lacus molestie. In auctor posuere ipsum, id venenatis orci pellentesque at. Pellentesque finibus justo eget velit fermentum rutrum. Aenean auctor urna
    sit amet nisi ullamcorper dapibus. Sed feugiat dolor ut nisi pharetra, vel pharetra metus semper. Aenean mattis suscipit venenatis. Suspendisse hendrerit consequat lacus, a rhoncus purus.
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

([*jsfiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/suburban_shawty/3wopkL9s/3/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close. Just add the following ...

```
.astro, .astro > img {
  height: 550px;
}
```

... and remove `height: 550px` from your `img` tags, while change your `position: fixed` to `position: absolute` in your `img` tags.

```css
.astro {
  position: relative;
}

.astro, .astro > img {
  height: 550px;
}

.astro > img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  91.66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="astro">
  <img src="https://images.complex.com/complex/images/c_crop,h_1009,w_1793,x_35,y_191/c_fill,g_center,w_1200/fl_lossy,pg_1,q_auto/bml3jrfcmmnhveupv5wq/astroworld-lead-sarah-montgomery" />
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DsRG3ldU0AAmswD.jpg:large" />
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtEDa3EUcAA_QJ6.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="tour-bio">
  <h3>ASTROWORLD:Wish you Were Here Tour </h3>
  <p>Praesent luctus dapibus felis sit amet egestas. Donec dignissim sapien eget erat euismod, ac euismod lacus molestie. In auctor posuere ipsum, id venenatis orci pellentesque at. Pellentesque finibus justo eget velit fermentum rutrum. Aenean auctor urna
    sit amet nisi ullamcorper dapibus. Sed feugiat dolor ut nisi pharetra, vel pharetra metus semper. Aenean mattis suscipit venenatis. Suspendisse hendrerit consequat lacus, a rhoncus purus.
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! That worked perfectly, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use position `absolute` and not `fixed` and also give the astro div height, it's height is 0 since all the content is positioned absolutely.

```css
.astro {
  position: relative;
  height: 670px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 550px;
  width: 100%;
  animation: slideshow 12s linear 0s infinite;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 2;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 1;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes slideshow {
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  91.66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="astro">
  <img src="https://images.complex.com/complex/images/c_crop,h_1009,w_1793,x_35,y_191/c_fill,g_center,w_1200/fl_lossy,pg_1,q_auto/bml3jrfcmmnhveupv5wq/astroworld-lead-sarah-montgomery" />
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DsRG3ldU0AAmswD.jpg:large" />
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DtEDa3EUcAA_QJ6.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="tour-bio">
  <h3>ASTROWORLD:Wish you Were Here Tour </h3>
  <p>Praesent luctus dapibus felis sit amet egestas. Donec dignissim sapien eget erat euismod, ac euismod lacus molestie. In auctor posuere ipsum, id venenatis orci pellentesque at. Pellentesque finibus justo eget velit fermentum rutrum. Aenean auctor urna
    sit amet nisi ullamcorper dapibus. Sed feugiat dolor ut nisi pharetra, vel pharetra metus semper. Aenean mattis suscipit venenatis. Suspendisse hendrerit consequat lacus, a rhoncus purus.
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
```